# Increase recall for minority class in XGBClassifier

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I'm using `XGBClassifier` to predict whether a user will click an ad or not.
I'm looking for advice to increase my recall for minority class.

**About my data:**

```
1. Total rows: 1,266,267
2. Total clicks: 1960 rows (0.15%) => imbalanced dataset
3. Features used:
    - Num of views 
    - Device used 
    - Time (categorized into 6 buckets)
    - Ad category
    - Site id (there are 338 unique site id)
    - User features (there are 583 unique features)(Note: features available for 60% of the data)
```

After one hot encoding, total columns/features is 943.
Final data in sparse matrix format.

**Model result:**

```
Model                   | AUC    | Logloss | Recall* | Precision*
------------------------|--------|---------|---------|-----------
Using all 943 features  | 0.7359 | 0.05392 | 0.47    | 0.85
----------------------------------------------------------------
Clustered user features | 0.7548 | 0.05470 | 0.51    | 0.80
into groups             |
Final model features    |
num=361                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
*recall and precision refers to the minority class (click=1). 
**recall, precision for majority class (click=0) is 1.
```

To increase **recall** in imbalanced dataset, I've tried:

```
1. Undersampling (highest recall 0.92, but precision at 0.03)
2. SMOTE (highest recall 0.77, but precision at 0.05) 
3. Different algorithm (best is XGBoost)
4. Hyperparameter tuning (recall increased by 0.01)
```

**Question:**

1. Is my model too complex that it can't generalize well?
2. I have compared my AUC with results from other research papers.
   Research AUC ranges from `0.7` to `0.82`.
   But, none of them showed the recall/confusion matrix.
   To anyone that has done CTR prediction before, can I know your recall/confusion matrix?
3. Is there other ways that can help increase recall for imbalanced dataset?

Comment: Maybe adding new features would help. Do you have features based on preceding clicks?

Comment: Other features like ad _format (eg:mobile, video, pull-ups) was not added as they have almost similar click rate. Based on EDA, the chosen 6 features showed impact on the clicks. I did try adding those features but the recall is still around 0.45 to 0.5.

Comment: What about features based on historical clicks (second part of my question) For example number of times the user clicked on an ad in last 1 hour? Or, number of clicks in last 10 minutes. etc Could this be predictive?

Comment: The number of clicks for each user for each ad is limited to 2. Hence, the low total click rows. More than 2 we consider it as fraud click. So, for this new suggested feature, the value will be between 0-2. Not sure if it will have a predictive value. Regardless, I will try first and update you the result.

Comment: I've tried adding historical clicks. Not much difference in the recall.

Answer (score 0):

Also, will suggest try other things such as: Using SMOTE (50%/50%) balance if your data is imbalanced, try other types of encoding if you have many categorical variables...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the sample_weight on samples of the minority class

`clf.fit(X_train, Y_train,sample_weight=sample_weight)`

where sample_weight is an array of doubles with length equal to the number of samples